# PHP MySQL database integration blueimp - Query File- pload

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, file-upload, blueimp

He there, I'm hoping someone here can assist me.

I'm using the blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload plugin

I have read this about 1000 times but I'm not good enough at PHP to understand how the classes work and i cant afford to loose any more hair.
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/PHP-MySQL-database-integration

I can see that for every file upload submitted from the form a separate POST is sent, I have 6 file names I need to store in a database in individual cells. _fileOne, _fileTwo etc.

If all 6 files were in one post I could access the file names in the $_FILES array but as each has an individual POST I don't know if it's even possible PHP to access 6 POST data?

I have managed to get the files uploaded, resized, moved and renamed to a new location but simply cant work out how to store the data i want in the DB.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

I guess I'm looking to develop a simplified version of the above link.

thank you

J